# VGroup or List doesn't fit into TileWindow, is too high

Tags: list, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

Does anybody please know, how to make the List and Checkbox (inside a VGroup) to fit into a [TileWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TitleWindow.html)?

[image: screenshot]

The complete source code **Text.mxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <s:TitleWindow width="240" height="240"
                   title="Why is List so tall?">
        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="20" paddingTop="20" 
                  paddingRight="20" gap="20" 
                  width="100%" height="100%">

            <s:List>
                <s:ArrayList>
                    <fx:String>10♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Д♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>К♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>10♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Д♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>К♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>10♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Д♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>К♠</fx:String>
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:List>

            <s:CheckBox label="Confirm bid" />

        </s:VGroup>
    </s:TitleWindow>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specifying a size, the List is measuring and sizing itself.

Add width and height to the List:

```
        <s:List width="100%"
                height="100%">
```

Which produces:

[image]

Full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955"
               minHeight="600">

    <s:TitleWindow width="240"
                   height="240"
                   title="Why is List so tall?">
        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="20"
                  paddingTop="20"
                  paddingRight="20"
                  gap="20"
                  width="100%"
                  height="100%">

            <s:List width="100%"
                    height="100%">
                <s:ArrayList>
                    <fx:String>10♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Д♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>К♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>10♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Д♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>К♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>10♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Д♠</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>К♠</fx:String>
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:List>

            <s:CheckBox label="Confirm bid" />

        </s:VGroup>
    </s:TitleWindow>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks, but why height="100%"? Does this leave any place for the checkbox underneath?

Comment: Give the List an explicit height, or group the CheckBox and List in a container, or specify top left right bottom and allow for CheckBox height on the bottom property with a regular Group.  Vertical layout of elements in the VGroup may depend on whether you want them spaced with your gap of 20.